# SQLAlchemy Classical Mapping Model to sharded Postgres databases

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mapping, sharding

**The situation:**

I have a set of 12 tables (representing data by month) that are sharded across 6 databases. I need to get a sample set of data across any of these databases for any given month.

**Why I used Classical Mappping Model rather than Declarative Model:**

I only require access to 1 of the 12 types of table as I will only be gathering a sample of data for a single given month each time this code is run. The Classical Mapping Model allows me to dynamically define the table name I want to map to at run time, rather than create mappings for all 12 tables across the 6 databases as I believe would be required with Declarative.

**The problem:**

I am trying to follow the [entity_name example given here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName) mapping my month data class to each of the tables for the given month on the 6 different databases.

But am getting an `UnmappedClassError` stating that my base class, which all new classes are derived from, 'is not mapped'.

So on trying to initialise one of my new mapped tables `type: <class '__main__.db1month1'>` it is reporting `UnmappedClassError: Class 'audit.db.orm.mappedclasses.MonthData' is not mapped`.

Any ideas?

If needed I can paste in my code here but I'm worried it's a little long. I am using the `map_class_to_some_table` method defined in the entity_name example for the mappings and haven't altered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up scrapping all that and following [this ShardedSession example](https://github.com/simplegeo/sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/sharding/attribute_shard.py) instead.

My final class looks something like this:

```
class ShardSessionManager(object):

    def __init__(self, month):
        self.month = month

        #Step1: database engines
        self.engines = {}
        for name, db in shard_dbs.iteritems():
            self.engines[name] = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=db.get_connection, client_encoding='utf8')

        #Step2: create session function - bind shard ids to databases within a ShardedSession
        self.create_session = sessionmaker(class_=ShardedSession)
        self.create_session.configure(shards=self.engines,
                                      shard_chooser=self.shard_chooser, 
                                      id_chooser=self.id_chooser, 
                                      query_chooser=self.query_chooser)
        #Step3: table setup
        self._make_tables(self.month)

        #Step4: map classes
        self._map_tables()

    @staticmethod
    def shard_chooser(mapper, instance, clause=None):
        if isinstance(instance, DataTable):
            return id_chooser(instance.brand_id)

    @staticmethod
    def id_chooser(data_id):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def query_chooser(query):
        ...

    def _make_tables(self, month):
        self.meta = MetaData()
        self.data_table = DataTable(month, self.meta).table 
        ... other tables ...

    def _map_tables(self):
        try:
            mapper(DataTable, self.data_table, 
                   properties={ ... })
            ...

    def get_random_data(self, parent_id):
        session = self.create_session()
        return session.query(DataTable).filter(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet same situation. My method below:

```
class_registry = {}                                                                                                                                                                    
DbBase = declarative_base(bind=engine, class_registry=class_registry)

def get_model(modelname, tablename, metadata=DbBase.metadata):
    if modelname not in class_registry: 
        model = type(modelname, (DbBase,), dict(
            __table__ = Table(tablename, metadata, autoload=True)
        ))  
    else:
        model = class_registry[modelname]
return model
```

It work well.But @Katie ‘s method is better